# How to Format data read from a file in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a project that is meant to read and write data to and from a file and display it in a given format.For example, if the file was meant to hold contact information like name, age and phone number, i want to have output in the form of:

```
    name : ****** , age: **, phone Number: ***.
```

How would i be able to do this?

By the way here is the block of code meant to read the data from the file using the FileReader and BufferedReader classes.

```
     while (line != null) {
            if (line.contains(name)) {
                data += line+"\n";
            }
            line = buff.readLine();
        }
        freader.close();
        buff.close();
        if(data.length() > 0){
        System.out.println("DATA FOUND! \n"+data);
        }else{
        System.out.println("DATA NOT FOUND");
        }
```

Comment: Try to write some code to do the data formatting and then post your code if you face any issue.

Comment: Adding to @saurav's comment, form the data string for each line in the format you want to write and then write it to file

Answer (score 0):

An straight forward and easy way of formatting a string in java is using the static method [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). You can supply a [format string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and the coresponding arguments.

So, for your example it would be:

```
String.format ("name : %s , age: %d, phone Number: %s.", name, age, phone);
```

For reading data you would have to write a parser to extract the data from each line.